# VS2015 C++ debugger weird result when reading structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio

While debugging I found the following weird results while iterating in the "test" function from the sample below:

[image]

The final result shows up correctly as 1. The values are only incorrect while inside the "test" function. Can someone shed some light on this?

It definitely has something to do with the DEBUG x64 version, x86 doesn't have this problem. I tried aligning the structure above to 4 bytes, and added some padding, but both made no difference.

Minimalistic sample code, compile on (x64):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

struct float3
{
    float3(float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) {}
    float x, y, z;
};

float test(float3 f)
{
    float x = f.x;
    return f.x; // Breakpoint here shows the results from image
}

int main()
{
    float3 a = float3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    float x = test(a);
    printf("%f %f", x, a.x);
}
```

Comment: Is this in release or debug build mode?

Comment: The debug version, edited post.

Comment: Since you're not using `f` after that line the compiler may have already overwritten it with something else.

Comment: Changing the test function to: 

float test(float3 f)
 {
  float x = f.x;
  float3 a = f;
  float y = a.x + f.y;
  return f.x;
 }
would include f, but didn't change the result

Comment: You're using the debug configuration, but can you ensure that optimizations are turned off?

Comment: I see it, the new debugging engine in VS2015 is a bad bag 'o bugs.  Workaround is Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatility Mode" checkbox.  You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Not entirely sure, I just added: #pragma optimize( "apgswy", {off} ) above the test function. I believe that ensures there are no optimizations. The result didn't change.

Comment: @HansPassant I checked the box, but didn't see any difference. Do you have any other non-default settings enabled?

Comment: Checking the "Use Native Compatability Mode" in the same menu as @HansPassant answer corrected the error. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant that one.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference,

As Hans Passant mentions in the comments, this question is solved by enabling the "Use Native Compatability Mode" option in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.